# cant find boost include directories system

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am getting the following output:

```
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1658 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "ON"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1659 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "OFF"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1660 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = "OFF"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1661 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1662 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] BOOST_ROOT = "/usr/include/boost"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1695 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1696 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1697 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1698 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1699 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1771 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "/usr/include/boost/include;/usr/include/boost;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1772 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = "boost-1_75_0;boost_1_75_0;boost/boost-1_75_0;boost/boost_1_75_0;boost-1_75;boost_1_75;boost/boost-1_75;boost/boost_1_75;boost-1_74_0;boost_1_74_0;boost/boost-1_74_0;boost/boost_1_74_0;boost-1_74;boost_1_74;boost/boost-1_74;boost/boost_1_74;boost-1_73_0;boost_1_73_0;boost/boost-1_73_0;boost/boost_1_73_0;boost-1_73;boost_1_73;boost/boost-1_73;boost/boost_1_73;boost-1_72_0;boost_1_72_0;boost/boost-1_72_0;boost/boost_1_72_0;boost-1_72;boost_1_72;boost/boost-1_72;boost/boost_1_72;boost-1_71_0;boost_1_71_0;boost/boost-1_71_0;boost/boost_1_71_0;boost-1_71;boost_1_71;boost/boost-1_71;boost/boost_1_71;boost-1_70_0;boost_1_70_0;boost/boost-1_70_0;boost/boost_1_70_0;boost-1_70;boost_1_70;boost/boost-1_70;boost/boost_1_70;boost-1_69_0;boost_1_69_0;boost/boost-1_69_0;boost/boost_1_69_0;boost-1_69;boost_1_69;boost/boost-1_69;boost/boost_1_69;boost-1_68_0;boost_1_68_0;boost/boost-1_68_0;boost/boost_1_68_0;boost-1_68;boost_1_68;boost/boost-1_68;boost/boost_1_68;boost-1_67_0;boost_1_67_0;boost/boost-1_67_0;boost/boost_1_67_0;boost-1_67;boost_1_67;boost/boost-1_67;boost/boost_1_67;boost-1_66_0;boost_1_66_0;boost/boost-1_66_0;boost/boost_1_66_0;boost-1_66;boost_1_66;boost/boost-1_66;boost/boost_1_66;boost-1_65_1;boost_1_65_1;boost/boost-1_65_1;boost/boost_1_65_1;boost-1_65_0;boost_1_65_0;boost/boost-1_65_0;boost/boost_1_65_0;boost-1_65;boost_1_65;boost/boost-1_65;boost/boost_1_65;boost-1_64_0;boost_1_64_0;boost/boost-1_64_0;boost/boost_1_64_0;boost-1_64;boost_1_64;boost/boost-1_64;boost/boost_1_64;boost-1_63_0;boost_1_63_0;boost/boost-1_63_0;boost/boost_1_63_0;boost-1_63;boost_1_63;boost/boost-1_63;boost/boost_1_63;boost-1_62_0;boost_1_62_0;boost/boost-1_62_0;boost/boost_1_62_0;boost-1_62;boost_1_62;boost/boost-1_62;boost/boost_1_62;boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost/boost-1_47_0;boost/boost_1_47_0;boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost/boost-1_47;boost/boost_1_47;boost-1_46_1;boost_1_46_1;boost/boost-1_46_1;boost/boost_1_46_1;boost-1_46_0;boost_1_46_0;boost/boost-1_46_0;boost/boost_1_46_0;boost-1_46;boost_1_46;boost/boost-1_46;boost/boost_1_46;boost-1_45_0;boost_1_45_0;boost/boost-1_45_0;boost/boost_1_45_0;boost-1_45;boost_1_45;boost/boost-1_45;boost/boost_1_45;boost-1_44_0;boost_1_44_0;boost/boost-1_44_0;boost/boost_1_44_0;boost-1_44;boost_1_44;boost/boost-1_44;boost/boost_1_44;boost-1_43_0;boost_1_43_0;boost/boost-1_43_0;boost/boost_1_43_0;boost-1_43;boost_1_43;boost/boost-1_43;boost/boost_1_43;boost-1_42_0;boost_1_42_0;boost/boost-1_42_0;boost/boost_1_42_0;boost-1_42;boost_1_42;boost/boost-1_42;boost/boost_1_42;boost-1_41_0;boost_1_41_0;boost/boost-1_41_0;boost/boost_1_41_0;boost-1_41;boost_1_41;boost/boost-1_41;boost/boost_1_41;boost-1_40_0;boost_1_40_0;boost/boost-1_40_0;boost/boost_1_40_0;boost-1_40;boost_1_40;boost/boost-1_40;boost/boost_1_40;boost-1_39_0;boost_1_39_0;boost/boost-1_39_0;boost/boost_1_39_0;boost-1_39;boost_1_39;boost/boost-1_39;boost/boost_1_39;boost-1_38_0;boost_1_38_0;boost/boost-1_38_0;boost/boost_1_38_0;boost-1_38;boost_1_38;boost/boost-1_38;boost/boost_1_38;boost-1_37_0;boost_1_37_0;boost/boost-1_37_0;boost/boost_1_37_0;boost-1_37;boost_1_37;boost/boost-1_37;boost/boost_1_37;boost-1_36_1;boost_1_36_1;boost/boost-1_36_1;boost/boost_1_36_1;boost-1_36_0;boost_1_36_0;boost/boost-1_36_0;boost/boost_1_36_0;boost-1_36;boost_1_36;boost/boost-1_36;boost/boost_1_36;boost-1_35_1;boost_1_35_1;boost/boost-1_35_1;boost/boost_1_35_1;boost-1_35_0;boost_1_35_0;boost/boost-1_35_0;boost/boost_1_35_0;boost-1_35;boost_1_35;boost/boost-1_35;boost/boost_1_35;boost-1_34_1;boost_1_34_1;boost/boost-1_34_1;boost/boost_1_34_1;boost-1_34_0;boost_1_34_0;boost/boost-1_34_0;boost/boost_1_34_0;boost-1_34;boost_1_34;boost/boost-1_34;boost/boost_1_34;boost-1_33_1;boost_1_33_1;boost/boost-1_33_1;boost/boost_1_33_1;boost-1_33_0;boost_1_33_0;boost/boost-1_33_0;boost/boost_1_33_0;boost-1_33;boost_1_33;boost/boost-1_33;boost/boost_1_33"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1857 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1858 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-gcc" (guessed)
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1894 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1972 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1976 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1977 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2037 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/usr/include/boost/lib;/usr/include/boost/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2038 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/usr/include/boost/lib;/usr/include/boost/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2223 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc-mt-;boost_system-gcc-mt;boost_system-gcc-mt;boost_system-mt-;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2278 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-gcc-mt-d-;boost_system-gcc-mt-d;boost_system-gcc-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
CMake Error at /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2344 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)
```

For a cmake file that looks like this:

```
...
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/include/boost")

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE BEAST_FILES
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}/boost/beast/*.hpp
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}/boost/beast/*.ipp)

source_group(TREE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}/boost/beast PREFIX beast FILES ${BEAST_FILES})

...
```

With these configurations I used to compile the project just fine a while ago!
How can I successfully find the required headers?

Comment: So, which **exact path** to the header `version.hpp`, belonging to Boost, on your machine?

Comment: boost for me is located here `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/` I'm not sure where version.hpp is.

Comment: You set `BOOST_ROOT` variable to `/usr/include/boost`, so probably boost headers are somewhere under this directory. Otherwise, why do you ever set this variable? How have you installed Boost on your machine? Have you installed it via package manager? Or have you built Boost from sources?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've installed it using Ubuntu's package manager. And yes, I just checked, `version.hpp` and the headers are in `/usr/include/boost`

Comment: CMake normally is able to find packages installed via system's package manager. No needs to set `BOOST_ROOT` variable. Probably, your setting confuses CMake, as `/usr/include/boost` is neither a **root** of your Boost installation, nor even its **include directory** (the latter one is `/usr/include`, because inclusion of Boost headers is performed via `#include <boost/smth.h>`).

Comment: The problem persist with or without setting root. I originally did not have that line, but I set it up trying to fix the issue.

Comment: Where is `BoostConfig.cmake` (or `boost-config.cmake`) located? For me it's at `.../boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake` and I'd expect it to be at `/usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake`, so `BOOST_ROOT` should afaik be just `/usr` (or simply left out. You could also use `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system CONFIG)` to not use the cmake find module for boost and instead use the package configuration scripts directly which should pick up on your boost installation, even if no info about its location is provided (at least in this scenario with default install loc)